# React doesn't execute function in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I'm currently trying to learn React and next.js with firebase as the database. I have a function in my component but for some reason it doesn't get called (i.e. I'm trying to do console.logs() but they don't work so i'm assuming the function is not called).

This is the code I have, it tries to fetch data from the firebase and then display it in the rendered component:

```
import React from 'react'
import {loadFirebase} from '../lib/db.js'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

export default class Item_Farm extends React.Component{

static async getInititalProps() {
    console.log("hallo")
    let firebase = loadFirebase()
    let result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('farms')
        .limit(10)
        .get()
        .then(snapshot => {
            let data = []
            console.log(snapshot)
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                data.push(
                    Object.assign({
                        id: doc.id
                    }, doc.data())
                )
            })
            resolve(data)
        })

        .catch(error => {
            reject([])
        })
    })
    return {farms: result}
}
render(){
    const farms = this.props.farms
    return(

    <div id="farms">
        {(farms && farms.length > 0)}
        <ul>
                {farms.map(farm => <li key="{farm.id}"><h1>{farm.name}</h1></li> )}
        </ul>

        <style jsx>{`
      div {
        background-color:  blue;
      }
    `}</style>

    </div>)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo mistake in function name. It should be

```
getInitialProps
```

For more info please check [fetch data next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#fetching-data-and-component-lifecycle)

Comment: Thsnks for the quick answer and for pointing out a typo I haven't noticed for 6 straight hours. Though the function still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

changes done in the code:
1. you are not calling getInititalProps function, calling it in componentDidMount is the best option
2. using state to re-render the view with firestore response

I didn't test the code. please check it and report any errors in comment.

```
    export default class Item_Farm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      farms: []
    }
    this.getInititalProps = this.getInititalProps.bind(this);
  }

  async getInititalProps() {
    let firebase = loadFirebase()
    try {
      let reqPromise = firebase.firestore().collection('farms').limit(10).get();
      let snapshot = await reqPromise;
      let data = snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        return Object.assign({
          id: doc.id
        }, doc.data());
      });
      this.setSate({
        farms: data
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getInititalProps();
  }

  render() {
    const { farms } = this.state;
    return (

      <div id="farms" style={{ backgroundColor: "red" }}>
        <ul>
          {
            (farms && farms.length > 0) ?
              farms.map(farm => (<li key={farm.id}>
                <h1>
                  {farm.name}
                </h1>
              </li>))
              :
              null
          }
        </ul>
      </div>)
  }
}
```

I hope it will work. 
best of luck

Comment: Also, it looks like firebase methods already return a promise which you call call await on directly without wrapping with a new promise. `await firebase.firestore().collection('farms').get()`

Comment: I was too focused to make it work with current code that I didn't noticed. I am updating the code. Thanks for pointing out.